# Apache Phoenix Current Time

Tags: apache, apache-phoenix

I am trying Apache Phoenix with Hbase. When I run try to get current time using select `current_time()`, its giving me some weird value. (292278994-08-17 07:12:55.807). Similarly for `current_date()` or `now()` query. I am not able to understand what does this mean, and how to get the current time (as we get from mysql `now()` function). Because of this I am unable to set the data type for view column as Date or Timestamp, as its doing some weird conversion.

Can anyone help me figure out a solution for this.

Comment: Could you attach your full Query?

Comment: 1. select current_date()
2. select current_time()
3. select now()
All 3 give the same weird value

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can do `select current_time() from any_table` which will return the expected result

Comment: How to use same function `current_time()` with delete query to measure delete query execution time?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in 4.6.1 and 4.7 version of phoenix.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-2611

Comment: Where can I download the latest version (4.6.1 or 4.7). This page (http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/phoenix/) doesn't have the latest version.

Comment: You need to wait until 4.7 got released. It is expected to release soon.